# Matlab table: Error using table All table variables must have the same number of rows

Tags: matlab, statistics

I am stuck, working with the following code to create the table:

Matlab makes an error: "Error using table
All table variables must have the same number of rows...... in line:
Table1 = table(var1,var2,var3,var4,'VariableNames',varname,'RowNames',rowname);"

Thanks for your help!

```
varname = {'Std. deviation','Relative std. deviation','F.O. autocorrelation','Correlation with output'};
rowname = {'Y','C','I','H','P'};
var1 = [hp_ysd;hp_csd;hp_isd;hp_hsd;hp_psd];
var2 = [hp_yrsd;hp_crsd;hp_irsd;hp_hrsd;hp_prsd];
var3 = [hp_foa_y;hp_foa_c;hp_foa_i;hp_foa_h;hp_foa_p];
var4 = [hp_corr_yy;hp_corr_cy;hp_corr_iy;hp_corr_hy;hp_corr_py];
Table1 = table(var1,var2,var3,var4,'VariableNames',varname,'RowNames',rowname);
disp(Table1)
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it looks like each of your varN variables are the same length.
However, if you're getting that error message, my bet would be that one or more of your hp_XYZ variables has a length of more than one. If you're concatenating variables with `myv3 = [myv1; myv2]` and myv1 is actually of size(2,1), then myv3 will be of size(3,1), rather than (2,1) as you'd expect.

Make sure that all the following are true

```
size(var1) == size(var2)
size(var2) == size(var3)
size(var3) == size(var4)
```